# Is there an inexpensive test (IE: perhaps a form of litmus paper?) for keeping tabs on oral pH at home?

Tags: dentistry, test, acidic, fluoride

My [initial research into the effect of oral pH](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/19070/has-a-guideline-been-set-for-the-optimal-ph-level-in-the-mouth) on health [I came across an article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2878349/) that suggests that using fluoride products in an acidic environment has many negative effects on health and that 32% of American children suffer from fluorosis, mostly from naturally occurring fluoride in groundwater!

Given that information, what might be the best way to go about testing one's oral pH?

Comment: This question crosses the line into asking for medical advice. Just barely, but it does. Could you please edit your second paragraph and reword it to make it a general question and not a how-to for your own health?

Comment: @CareyGregory I understand. Did my change address your concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this medical/scientific article that reviews 3 different saliva pH testing kits](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1834-7819.2008.00023.x) including a litmus paper test.

Litmus paper strips are apparently ubiquitous and many such products available at Walmart, for example.